# loading the url without navigating to it with javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

Hi,

I have a button that executes a function. I want to be able to press it but without navigating away from the current page. I did this:

```
<a href="dostuff.php" onclick="return(false);">
```

it wont navigate away but it wont open the page either. Can it be done with javascript within the link without having to create an external function?

Thank you.

Comment: return is not a method....

Comment: How is it supposed to open up the page and not navigate away? I am not sure what you are expecting. Do you want a new window to open? my guess `<a href="dostuff.php" target="_blank">`

Comment: I guess a popup in place wouldnt hurt.

Comment: So use target....

Comment: that wont open a popup in place.

Comment: No clue what a "pop up in place" means... There is no magic HTML code that retrieves data from somewhere else and displays it in place.

Comment: a popup within the same window/tab

Comment: So you need to write an Ajax/fetch call, get the data, and display it on the page.....

Comment: I guess that cant be included within the same <a> element, right?

Comment: well you could do it inline, but that is not the best practice....

Comment: you mean like `<a href="#" onclick="$.ajax({url:dostuff.php}">`

Answer (score 0):

It should work without Using parentheses:

```html
<a href="dostuff.php" onclick="return false;">
```

Comment: sorry for it ;)

Comment: then it wont do anything. It wont navigate away but it wont open the page either.

Comment: What your want? Open the page in a new tab?